# how to restrict user to select only two days back date as well current date in date picker jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to restrict to user to select current date or at-least past two days back date from date picker calendar?

My code is:

```
$('#date1').datepick({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
var date1= $("#date1").val();
```

html code is:

```
<input type="text" id="date1" name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the `minDate` attribute for the `datepicker` config object like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-2);

$('#date1').datepick({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy', minDate: d});
var date1= $("#date1").val(); 
**html code is**
<input type="text" id="date1" name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

set the min and max date.

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
   minDate: -2,
   maxDate: 0,
});
```

Hop this helps. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/23L4fmmo/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    minDate: '-2'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sowchkho/)